# React-native-web does not install with React 18

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

[image]npm install react-native-web gives the following errors, I have other dependencies but singled on this one, a [bug][2] created for the same was also conveniently closed

```
npm install react-native-web
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mSales@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.18.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     react-native-web@"^0.18.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.18.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     react-native-web@"^0.18.10" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here a sample docker file

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install react-native-web
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "web" ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatched versions of react and react-dom. Try;

```
npm install react-dom@18.1.0 react-native-web@0.18.10
```